# How is experience calculated in Pocket Planes?

Tags: pocket-planes

I'm not sure how experience is calculated in Pocket Planes. How is experience generated?

Answer (score 2):

Trying to build an answer, I just tried and checked in the stats view to see what was going on after each action (Lot of question marks remaining for now but already some answers).
Here are my conclusions at the moment (feel free to edit/comment of course):

- Loading something/someone in a plane at the airport: +1XP (even if you unload it after)
- Trip: gross amount added to the exp (not the profit)
- Catch a coin during flight: +1 XP
- Catch a big coin during flight: +1 XP
- Catch a buck during flight: +1 XP
- Buying a plane part: +1 XP (done on a Birchcraft-C Engine for 7 bucks)
- Buying a plane: ?
- Buying a new airport: 0 XP (when buying Houston)
- Advertise in an airport: ?
- Upgrade an airport: ?
- Upgrade a plane: ?
- Buying a plane slot: ?

Comment: LudoMC, you are backwards in your first point. Unloading someone loses you 1XP (-1XP), which makes sense, you have to choose carefully. EDIT: Never mind, it makes sense, but I didn't realize that the experience was counting down to next level. LudoMC you were correct, sorry about that.

Comment: I keep meaning to come back and verify this, I just keep forgetting. My initial tests made it look like you didn't get experience for just loading things onto a plane; it only ticked when a flight landed.

Comment: Don't you get exp for earning money? (I noticed it was around 1 coin = 1 EXP. This also includes the fraction of the profit that ends up getting spent as fuel)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure. The three most obvious theories are flights landed, miles flown, or profit generated. Profit generated I think is unlikely, for a number of reasons. It would be difficult to distinguish between flights landed and miles flown without specific experimentation and math, which I haven't done, or being directly told by one of the games designers which is what I hope will at some point happen.